# CakePHP Auth Component Check User Before Login

Tags: cakephp, authentication, components, verify

I want to prevent banned users from logging in to the site and give them a message that they are banned. I tried to use isAuthorized() for this but it allows the user to login and only after that denies him permission to the unauthorized actions.

So, basically I want to know where to put the condition that would check if the user table as banned = true, before the login process takes place. Right now my login function is empty as its being automatically controlled by the Auth Component.

Comment: As @benjamin pointed out, there are SIMPLE self-checking strategies... The simplest, at [controller](http://api.cakephp.org/file/Cake/Controller/Component/SessionComponent.php) or *view_file.ctp*, is `if ( $this->Session->check('Auth.User') ) doSomeThing()`.

Comment: To those who got here searching for an answer (just like me), if you're trying to use the `$components` directly then the key name should be `scope`, not `userScope`. All credits to the answer by @Matthew below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution by going through the API. I wonder if anyone has used this ever, cause nobody pointed me to this, or maybe I wasn't clear enough. Anyways, to add a condition to the login process you just have put it in the variable $this->Auth->userScope

So, to check if a user is banned I just added this line to the beforeFilter() in my AppController,

```
$this->Auth->userScope = array('User.banned'=>0);
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is more commonly written as `$this->Auth->userScope = array('User.active' => 1);`

Comment: ya one and the same thing... but atleast i know now where to put these conditions :)

Comment: How would you distinguish between "Incorrect Credentials" and "User is banned" if you use this way?

Comment: What credentials are you talking about?

Comment: how to do u differentiate if the username and password is right and the persons account is not activated thru email yet. how on login.. can u tell him that the Account is not yet activated so we are not letting him in. and other posibility is account is active and user entered pass or username is wrong tell him its wrong so we are not letting him. how to set $this->Auth->loginError differently for these two posibilities

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively to:
`$this->Auth->userScope = array('User.banned'=>0);`

This can be done when you include your Auth Component. This probably saves some tiny amount of overhead as `$this->Auth->userScope` isn't called every time a controller is parsed.

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish',
                'scope' => array('User.banned' => 0)
            )
        ),
        'authorize' => array('Controller')
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks @Matthew, this has actually helped me a lot as I was trying to use the `userScope` as an array key.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the whole Auth system already up and running, why don't you just follow the KISS principle and revoke their password or alter there username? If they are not longer able to authenticate with your system as they could earlier they should be able to deduce that they are banned.

If that doesn't suffice, then additionally you could add the code below.

```
function login() {
  if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
    $this->Session->setFlash('You are alreadylogged in!~~~~~~~~~~~');   
  }
  $this->Session->setFlash('You have been banned!');    
  $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'index'));
}
```

Edit 1: For a more dynamically approach like you pointed out in your comment, you could check the is_banned column of the user record under concern in your `UsersController::beforeFilter()` and set your flash message accordingly. Also make a redirect based on the outcome of `$this->Session->read('Auth.User.is_banned')`. Maybe you want to have a look at the output of `<?php debug $this->Session->read('Auth.User) ?>` before attacking your problem.

Edit 2: My fault. You could store the is_banned somewhere in the Session via `$this->Session->write(...)`. After you read an `is_banned = true` you can log the user out.

Comment: well... that would be complicated as i want the admin to able to ban and also unban a user whenever need arises. changing the username or password would require me to keep record of the same if i want to change it back to the original.

Comment: @edit: i am not sure how that would work... its not even checking if the user has banned field set to true.

Comment: i am confused by your last comment. i just committed and your comment to my edit is already in place??

Comment: :D the comment on the edit was actually for the login function code that you added later on. anyways, i will try using the beforeFilter() but really isn't there something that i can do in the login function itself? anyways, thanks for the help so far.

Comment: aadravid, to be straight out honest, you should have a look at Niks solution, before turning to mine. chances are that it serves you better. Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

you have to use:

```
/** Function is executed after the login*/
function isAuthorized() {
return true;
}
```

where you can check if the user is banned or no. i.e.

```
/** Function is executed after the login*/
function isAuthorized() {
if($this->Auth->user('banned') == 1){ //column banned should be in the users table
       $this->Session->setFlash('You have been banned!');    
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I believe this is the correct way.

Comment: well, this is how i am doing it currently, but this lets the user login and then tells him that he is banned. i just wanted to know if it can be done before logging him in.

Comment: Well, how could you determine that the user is banned if he is not identified :) Basically in that function you have to redirect the user to the logout action (if he is banned), so he will be logged out immediately after the banned field is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Having read your last comment on Nik's way, I think that you could just refine your original solution by logging the user out manually via $this->Auth->logout() at the appropriate place in your code (followed by a redirect). This way it should look like he/she never logged in.

Comment: you are right... was thinking on the same lines and i guess that's the easiest solution for this. thanks all of you.